# Animation: Rigid body physics on chain links how to move the object?

Tags: animation, physics

What I want to do: One plate fixed to "wall" chain linked to cuff on hand of the armature. move arm chain gets tighter or looser.

Newb Question. I created individual links in a chain; added rigid body physics; played with the settings a bit. 2 fixed endpoints - chain has physics. hit space bar chain falls but held at both ends - very nice.

now I want to move on end over timeline as well so that it gets looser.

START
[image]

After Physics Animation
[image]

All Works well!
Obviously in object mode grabbing just moves individual objects (single chain links)
but what I want is to move the cuff left and the chain gets tighter over timeline as well. Loose to taught. But how do you do that when they are all individual bits.

You cant move timeline, then move the object and take a keyframe - or do you have to move every chain link independently?

-- Ignore the curve I was just testing yet another option (it's not linked)

Any Ideas.

Basically, if it could apply the physics as I move in object mode that would be cool - but I can't see how you can do that. Any help/alternatives greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u provide your blend file?